VBA Find and FindNext unable to match a string (with CR or LF inside)
I have datatable with records.
Each record has a tagcode in col A
This tagcode is not unique, it is the functional name of the record and 1 funcitonal item can have several records in the table with the same tagcode
I need a macro function to get certain information from all records with a given tagcode.
The logical way is to use Find and FindNext , like I've done so many times
But his time.. it just doesn't work. I tried so many things/variant .. and still not working 100% as it should: sometimes finds 1 record, sometimes none, sometimes several, sometimes all.
The paticular thing is (which is maybe the cause): the tagcode often has a char(10) inside.
See function below. The function is called from the table itself and the kabelCell argument is a cell on the record row. So there MUST always be at least 1 matching record.
(if tagcode is empty then the code assumes this is an error and just returns the info of the line, it's not looking for other empty tagcodes)
    Function KabelTrajectInfo(kabelCell As Range) As String
    
    Dim rij As Integer
    
    rij = kabelCell.Row
    
    Dim KcellCol As New Collection
    Dim Kcell As Range
    Dim firstRow As Long
    Dim tagcode As String

    tagcode = kabelCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Text 'also tried with .Value and .Formula
    
    With Intersect(Sheets("Kabels").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Kabels").UsedRange)
        If tagcode = "" Then
            Set Kcell = kabelCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
        Else
            'find: also tried with lookin xlFormulas and xlFormulas2
            Set Kcell = .Find(What:=tagcode, _
                After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:= _
                xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)

            'strange: sometimes not found, so check with match: this ALWAYS finds the 1st matching row
            If Kcell Is Nothing Then 
                firstRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(tagcode, .Cells, 0)
                If firstRow = 0 Then
                    Set Kcell = kabelCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
                Else
                    Set Kcell = Sheets("Kabels").Cells(firstRow, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        firstRow = Kcell.Row
        
        While Not Kcell Is Nothing
            KcellCol.Add Item:=Kcell

            'initial logical solution with findnext: never finds the next one
            Set Kcell = .FindNext(Kcell)

            'backup solution with Find and own check to prevent loop: sometimes finds the other one, but often not all or not the last one
            If tagcode <> "" Then Set Kcell = .Find(What:=tagcode, After:=Kcell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False)
            If Not Kcell Is Nothing Then
                If Kcell.Row = firstRow Then Set Kcell = Nothing
            End If
        Wend
    End With
    
    For Each Kcell In KcellCol
    ... some code to create a tempStr
    Next Kcell

    KabelTrajectInfo = tempStr
End Function

I've spend so many hours on this to try out variants .. and I give up, so I address to you: does anybody habve an idea what I'm overlooking? Or is this an issue with char(10) in string matching?
Note: trying the find/next directly in the excel sheet (with the tagcode still stored from the VBA) DOES FIND ALL the records! Huh??
Note 2: this function is also used (and tested) as an UDF.. seems like this could relevant
Based on the feedback below I tested this:
Private Function getTagcodeCol2(tagcode As String) As Collection
    Dim tempCol As New Collection
    Dim c As Range
    
    For Each c In Intersect(Sheets("Kabels").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Kabels").UsedRange())
        If c.Text = tagcode Then tempCol.Add Item:=c
    Next c
    
    Debug.Print tagcode, tempCol.Count
    Set getTagcodeCol2 = tempCol
End Function
 
Private Function getTagcodeCol(tagcode As String) As Collection
    Dim KcellArr  As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Kabels").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    KcellArr = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(ROW(Kabels!A1:A" & lastrow & "),A1:A" & lastrow & "=""" & tagcode & ""","""")")
    
    Dim tempCol As New Collection
    Dim tel As Long
    'no error check because dim of array varies: if 1 found, then 1 dim array, if more than 1 found, then 2 dim
    On Error Resume Next
    For tel = 1 To UBound(KcellArr)
        tempCol.Add Item:=Sheets("Kabels").Cells(CLng(KcellArr(tel, 1)), 1)
        tempCol.Add Item:=Sheets("Kabels").Cells(CLng(KcellArr(tel)), 1)
    Next tel
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Debug.Print tagcode, tempCol.Count
    Set getTagcodeCol = tempCol
End Function
Private Function getTagcodeCol3(tagcode As String) As Collection
    Dim KcellArr  As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    KcellArr = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(ROW(Kabels!A:A),A:A=""" & tagcode & ""","""")")
    
    Dim tempCol As New Collection
    Dim tel As Long
    'no error check because dim of array varies: if 1 found, then 1 dim array, if more than 1 found, then 2 dim
    On Error Resume Next
    For tel = 1 To UBound(KcellArr)
        tempCol.Add Item:=Sheets("Kabels").Cells(CLng(KcellArr(tel, 1)), 1)
        tempCol.Add Item:=Sheets("Kabels").Cells(CLng(KcellArr(tel)), 1)
    Next tel
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Debug.Print tagcode, tempCol.Count
    Set getTagcodeCol3 = tempCol
End Function
Private Function getTagcodeCol4(tagcode As String) As Variant
    Dim KcellArr  As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    
    KcellArr = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(ROW(Kabels!A:A),A:A=""" & tagcode & ""","""")")
    
    'If UBound(KcellArr) = 1 Then KcellArr(1) = Array(KcellArr)
        
    Debug.Print tagcode, UBound(KcellArr)
    getTagcodeCol4 = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, KcellArr)
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim KcellCol  As Collection
    Dim KcellCol2 As Collection
    Dim KcellCol3  As Collection
    Dim KcellColStr  As String
    Dim tagcode As String
    tagcode = ActiveCell.Value
    '"LSBZ_LOTS04" & vbCr & "26 Q1_W1"
    '"DB_UPS_ROTS04_1X4_W1"
    
    Dim t1A, t1U, t2A, t2U, t3A, t3U, t4A, t4U As Variant
    Dim tel As Long
    Dim telmax As Long
    
    telmax = 200
    
    t1A = Now()
    For tel = 1 To telmax
        Set KcellCol = getTagcodeCol(tagcode)
    Next tel
    t1U = Now()
    
    t2A = Now()
    For tel = 1 To telmax
        Set KcellCol2 = getTagcodeCol2(tagcode)
    Next tel
    t2U = Now()
    
    t3A = Now()
    For tel = 1 To telmax
        Set KcellCol3 = getTagcodeCol3(tagcode)
    Next tel
    t3U = Now()
    
    t4A = Now()
    For tel = 1 To telmax
        KcellColStr = getTagcodeCol4(tagcode)
    Next tel
    t4U = Now()

    Debug.Print KcellCol.Count, KcellCol2.Count, KcellCol3.Count, UBound(Split(KcellColStr, ",")) + 1
    
    Debug.Print 24# * 3600 * (t1U - t1A), 24# * 3600 * (t2U - t2A), 24# * 3600 * (t3U - t3A), 24# * 3600 * (t4U - t4A)
    
End Sub

Result: only getTagcodeCol2 always gives the correct answer, the 3 other sometimes (but consistent between them)
Result: getTagcodelCol is 10 times faster than the three others, which are the same +- 5%
Thx,
Christof

.Text definitely wouldn't be the answer - that returns whatever format the cell is displaying.  If the column is too narrow it will return #####.

Please, try Debug.Print "_" & kabelCell & "_", instr(kabelCell, vbLf), instr(kabelCell, vbCr) as the first function code line.  And call the function using a cell containing the respective character(s) you suspect to be the cause of not working well. What does it return? Is it what you think it should? And the best way would be to use the cell Value.

If you use your function as a UDF, you cannot use FindNext in it, because this method does not work in the UDF.

The Debug.print resulted what I expected. But indeed, this function is both called in other macro's, but also as an UDF. And the checks I do is always on the UDF use... that explains. Why have I never seen this limitation in the docuemntation? Even on the microsoft site. Or did I overlook?

Documentation about FindNext is very poor. This method, for example, also ignores SearchFormat, which is also not written.

I think that instead of relying on Find and FindNext which can be finicky with embedded special characters, you could check directly each cell in UsedRange, something like:
   For Each cell In Intersect(ws.Range("A:A"), ws.UsedRange)
        ' Match the tagcode and handle CHAR(10)
        If Replace(cell.Text, vbLf, "") = Replace(tagcode, vbLf, "") Then
            KcellCol.Add cell
        End If
    Next cell


I have already a similar workaround running for the moment: I created a seperate function to build KcellCol with a "for each cell in usedrange" loop. But I am worried about performance: the table has 10k records so the macro is run 10k times, looking through 10k records ... whichis why I really wanted the 'find' solution as I thought that would be much faster.

I just tested and can now confirm: this solution is VERY slow in my context. (but it does work)

You can switch off automatic calculations

the only working solution was very slow, and the faster solution (with evaluate) is even no fast enough. Because 10k rows need updated, based on information in 10k rows over 600 column. So I built a 'cache' solution. as a result speed of the code itself not critical anymore. As long as the data doesn't change, the cache keeps the data and the macro reuses the cache to instantlly give the result.

Let's allow Excel to do its job!
KcellCol = Application.Evaluate("TEXTJOIN("","",TRUE,FILTER(B1:B8,A1:A8=""" & tagcode & """,""""))")

Or
  KcellCol = WorksheetFunction.Filter([B1:B8], Application.Evaluate("A1:A8 = """ & tagcode & """"), "")
  KcellStr = WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(",", True, KcellCol)

If you need points to matching cells:
  KcellCol = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(ROW(A1:A8),A1:A8=""" & tagcode & ""","""")")

It returns row indexes of matching cells.

The way to use the power of Excel is:

On a sheet, compose and debug the formula you need.
Insert this formula into the code.

You should be fluent to combine Excel functions and VBA.
Credits to @MGonet: If you need to ignore CR in the tagcodes, use:
  KcellCol = Application.Evaluate("FILTER(ROW(A1:A8),CLEAN(A1:A8)=""" & tagcode & ""","""")")


I'm learning new functions here, and I try to see what it does. Interesting :), even after 30y of VBA. Seems like the first evaluate gets a array of boolean based on colA matching, which is then given to Filter the relevant cells from colB. And then finally joined to a string with ',' seperation. OK. But how do I get the cell references or row numbers of the matching cells?

Please look at the update answer.

You can use CLEAN function to eliminate non-printable characters (0 to 31) from your data while filtering.

@MGonet I tested FILTER for a text with Chr(10) - it works.

@rotabor, It works, but it distinguishes between texts with Chr(10) and those without Chr(10). I checked in Excel, not with Evaluate, but it should be the same.

@MGonet Shure. It filters the exact match. Act accordingly if you need anything else.

@MGonet I've mentioned your proposition in the answer.

I was very hopefull so did some performance and accuracy test. I added code en results to my initial post (didn't find any other way .. not sure this is the correct way)

You can mark the answer as accepted if it helps.

Based on all the input I received and considering the speed needed and the large volume of data consulted each time (10k rows, with info in 600 columns), I built a cached solution, on top of the 'simple loop the table' macro.
So the datatable sheet has 2 cache collections (1 for raw tagcode data and 1 for tha calculated tagcode info string, based on 600 column info of all tagcode records). The cache of the tagcode related info is cleared whever something on the row of a tagcode is modified: so in the code of the datatable sheet:
Option Explicit
Public kCellCol As New Collection
Public kCellTraceCol As New Collection

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        On Error Resume Next
        kCellCol.Remove (c.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        kCellTraceCol.Remove (c.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next c
End Sub

Then, in the code/UDF that call to get the infoString or KcellCol of a tagcode, I try to retrieve it from the cache. If not there, I calculate (slowly) :) what's needed, put it in the cache and return the value:
Function KabelTrajectInfo(kabelCell As Range, Optional dummyRange As Range) As String
    Dim tagcode As String
    
    tagcode = kabelCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1).Value
    
    If tagcode = "" Then
        KabelTrajectInfo = calcKabelTrajectInfo(kabelCell)
        Debug.Print tagcode, "KcellInfo calc on blank"
    Else
        'first try to get it from cache
        On Error Resume Next
        KabelTrajectInfo = Blad1.kCellTraceCol(tagcode)
        If Err Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            Blad1.kCellTraceCol.Add Item:=calcKabelTrajectInfo(kabelCell), Key:=tagcode
        Else
            Debug.Print tagcode, "KcellInfo reuse"
        End If
        KabelTrajectInfo = Blad1.kCellTraceCol(tagcode)
    End If
End Function

The calcKabelTrajectInfo code does something similar and first looks if the KcellCol for that tagcode can be found in the cache, otherwise asks to do the actual scan loop, and build the string. To further optimise: while scanning all records  for 1 missing tagcode, the opportunity is taken to also add to the cache other missing tagcode info it finds, since everything is being scanned anyway.
 Function calcKabelTrajectInfo(kabelCell As Range, Optional dummyRange As Range) As String
...
'Find all records van de tagcode
    If tagcode = "" Then
        kCellCol.Add Item:=kabelCell.EntireRow.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        Set kCellCol = getTagcodeColFromCache(tagcode)
    End If
...
end
Private Function addTagcodeColToCache(tagcode As String) As Collection
    'gets the col and puts in cach, but while
    Dim tempCol As New Collection
    Dim c As Range
    
    Dim testCol As Collection

    'Loop through the tagcode of all records
    For Each c In Intersect(Sheets("Kabels").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Kabels").UsedRange())
        On Error Resume Next
        'check if also not missing from cache, so all missing in 1 go
        Set testCol = Blad1.kCellCol(c.Value)
        If Err Then
            tempCol.Add Item:=New Collection, Key:=c.Value
        End If
        
        tempCol(c.Value).Add Item:=c
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next c

    'add all new KcellCol's to the cache
    Dim col As Collection
    For Each col In tempCol
        Blad1.kCellCol.Add Item:=col, Key:=col(1).Value
    Next col
    
    Debug.Print tagcode, tempCol(tagcode).Count
    Set addTagcodeColToCache = tempCol(tagcode)
End Function
Private Function getTagcodeColFromCache(tagcode As String) As Collection
    Dim tempCol As Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set tempCol = Blad1.kCellCol(tagcode)
    If Err Then
        'Blad1.kCellCol.Add Item:=getTagcodeCol2(tagcode), Key:=tagcode
        Call addTagcodeColToCache(tagcode)
    Else
        Debug.Print tagcode, tempCol.Count, "reuse from cache"
    End If
    
    Set getTagcodeColFromCache = Blad1.kCellCol(tagcode)
End Function

Maybe it helps somebody.
Thanks for your support,
C.

If you need to optimize performance of your app, create a new question.
